# how to debug this query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

i want to write a query that has to give me the boat_id and average of that boat's sailor's age .
this is the database schema:

```
BOAT(bid , boatNAME ,color)
SAILOR(sailorID , sailorNAME , age , rating)
RESERVES(sailorID , bid , date)
```

```
select bid,avg(select sailors.age from sailors natural join reserves)  
from reserves natural join sailors
group by bid
having count(select age from sailors natural join reserves where age>40)>4
```

it gives me an error on the select that i wrote in the avg()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join and aggregate;

```
select b.bid, b.boatName, avg(s.age) avg_sailor_age
from boat b
inner join reserves r on r.bid = b.bid
inner join sailor s on s.sailorID = r.sailorID
group by b.bid, b.boatName
```

If you need only the id of boat, not any other information fro the `boat` table, 2 joins are enough:

```
select r.bid, avg(s.age) avg_sailor_age
from reserves r
inner join sailor s on s.sailorID = r.sailorID
group by r.bid
```

Notes:

- in general, avoid `natural join`s: they can bite you in may ways
- it is unclear what the purpose of the `having` clause of your existing query is; I left it apart for the time being.

---

**Edit**

If you want to filter on *boats that at least 4 sailors that reserved this boat have the age more than 40*, then you can add the following clause at the end of the query:

```
having sum( (s.age >= 40)::int ) >= 4
```

Comment: what if i had a condition.
look at the code i wrote , in the having part , i want the bid of the boats that at least 4 sailors that reserved this boat have the age more than 40

Comment: @amshakur: for this you need a `having` clause. I updated my answer.